# How to unlock a runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

## Context

I am the (beginner) admin of my company GitLab server and I have a shared runner that is locked for an unknown reason. I couldn't find any information about what it means to be locked (and the difference with "paused") or how a runner can get locked. I also tried to find a way to unlock it, but all I could find was "how to register an unlocked runner in the first place".

## What I did

1. Remove the runner from *https://gitlab.my-company.com/admin/runners*.
2. Unregister the runner with `gitlab-runner unregister the-runner-name`.
3. Register a new one with `gitlab-runner register --locked=false`.
4. Clean everything with `gitlab-runner verify --delete`.

## What I wanted to do

Edit the current runner with something like `gitlab-runner edit the-runner-name --locked=false`.

## What I wanted to do even more

Go to *https://gitlab.my-company.com/admin/runners* and click on **Unlock runner**.

## Question

Is there a way to unlock a runner or do I have to unregister it each time it's locked and register a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to runners page and click you runner (or Edit icon next to its name). It should lead you to a screen where you can remove Locked status.

You may be using some old version of gitlab or have no sufficient permissions if you can't access this screen.

Comment: You cannot remove the "locked" status. There is no such option

Comment: Make sure are clicking on the "pencil" icon, not on runner name

Comment: If you don't see the option, it's because you are trying to unlock a group runner.